# C# halt until button is pressed

Tags: c#

I'm building a calculator in c#. I want to halt the calculator with error sound until clear button is pressed. Like while calculating square root, the no. is -ve.

Here's the part of calculating square root

```
 private void buttonSquareRoot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        num1 = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        if (num1 < 0.0)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "Invalid Input";
        }
        else
        {
            result = Math.Sqrt(double.Parse(textBox1.Text));
            textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(result);
        }
    }
```

After error message i want program to halt until clear button is clicked. i have already made clear button which goes like this.

```
 private void buttonClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "";
    }
```

Comment: is it not working then?

Comment: Add a `private bool IsHalted` that defaults to false, and go true every time there's something that needs to be halted. Add checks throughout your code to examine the value and complain, and then return, if the value is true...

Comment: When you say you want the app halted, are you referring to disabling any further input apart from the Clear button?

Comment: You do now want Your program to halt.
You want it to react to nothing more than the clear-button, after it will react as before.
You can use a global variable, and set it.
Something like blClearRequired = false;
And set it to true, if the error occurrs.
In the clickhandler of each button You can just ask for the var and return wichtout doing anything, as long boolean var is true.
Clear buttons sets it to false, and all starts from the beginning.
Ok for  You ?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable all buttons you need until you need them again.

```
void SetControlsAbility(bool isEnabled)
{
    // for every control you need:
    yourControl.Enabled = isEnabled;
}
```

Then

```
private void buttonSquareRoot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    num1 = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    if (num1 < 0.0)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "Invalid Input";
        SetControlsAbility(false);
    }
    else
    {
        result = Math.Sqrt(double.Parse(textBox1.Text));
        textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(result);
    }
}
```

And

```
private void buttonClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = "";
    SetControlsAbility(true);
}
```

Comment: its solved. i made a bool variable and use it to control my program. thnx all for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void buttonSquareRoot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        num1 = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        if (num1 < 0.0)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "Invalid Input";
            **buttonSquareRoot.Enabled = False;**
        }
        else
        {
            result = Math.Sqrt(double.Parse(textBox1.Text));
            textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(result);
        }
    }


private void buttonClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "";
        buttonSquareRoot.Enabled = True;
    }
```